# extracting multiple characters from a nested list

Tags: python

I have a nested list (list with sub-lists):

```
x = [[12, 36, 2, 10, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3], [11, 36, 6, 7, 10, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],  [12, 36, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0], [13, 36, 4, 9, 2, 1, 7, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I would like to create a new nested list of say, the 3rd and 4th numbers of each sub-list:
    z = [[2,10],[6,7],[2, 1],[4, 9]]

I see that I can do a lot of appends like this:

```
y = []
y.append(x[0][2])
y.append(y[0][3])
z = []
z.append(y)
y = []
y.append(x[1][2])
y.append(x[1][3])
z.append(y)
y = []
y.append(x[2][2])
y.append(y[2][3])
z.append(y)
```

## now z = [[2,10],[6,7],[2, 1],[4, 9]]

The numbers that I want to extract may not be next to each other as is this example. This seems crude to me. I'd appreciate any help with this! thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible answer:

```
y = []
for i in x:
    y.append([i[2],i[3]])
```

BTW, you should add the python tag (and perhaps ditch all the others).